# How to properly include or require a file in an another folder from a file in an another folder

Tags: php

For example, I am going to require `index.php` (file found in config folder) in  `index.php` which is in the anotherfolder. I am just doing this `require dirname(__dir__).'config/index.php';` what I understand in this line is that it will get my working directory(blog1) and find the folder named config and see if there's an `index.php` in it. This would get the job done but I'm not sure if I am doing it right, and is my understanding is correct?

for example this is my directory:

- blog1

  - config

    - index.php
  - anotherfolder

    - index.php

If anyone can help me with my little problem that would be great, (don't mind the - sign I don't know how to else illustrate a directory.

Comment: Can you please clear if the config and anotherfolder directories at same level?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in **anotherfolder** and want to include *index.php* from **config** then use this code:

```
require __DIR__ . '/config/index.php';
```

P.S It is a good practice to define a common set of constants like `BASE_URL` and `BASE_PATH` in a **configuration** file and then include files with absolute addressing by using `BASE_PATH` e.g.

```
require BASE_PATH . '/file_name.php';
```

You should also make a habbit of that.